# Classifying values according to range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I have a column with values ranging from `0` to `5`.

I want to assign those numbers ranging from:

`0` to `1` to class i,
 `1` to `2.5` to class ii
 `2.5` to `4.5` to class iii
 and `4.5` and above to class iv

using Microsoft Excel.

How do I go about it?

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon I don't think this is a duplicate of that... it's probably a duplicate of something though.

Comment: In which class 1; 2.5 and 4.5  belong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can just build a nested IF.

Assuming your values start in cell A2:

=IF(A2<1,"class I",IF(A2<2.5,"class ii",IF(A2<4.5,"class iii","class iv")))

Comment: I think a VLOOKUP type approach might be a little more elegant, but you're right that with so few categories this is pretty simple.

Comment: I actually started typing out a Vlookup approach, but reverted to the simplistic option

Comment: Yes it seems it's more flexible - vlookup or match would give you <=1 etc. rather than <1 and a bit tricky to change it I think.

Answer (score 0):

A little shorter:

```
="class "&CHOOSE(LEFT(A1)+1,"i","ii","iii","iii","iv","iv")
```

Comment: I think you want something more like this ="class "&CHOOSE(LEFT(A5)+1,"i","ii","iii","iii","iv","iv") .... even then, it doesn't handle the 0.5 very well and is a more flaky solution since it doesn't handle the greater than 4.5 case very well.... notice that a value of 10 would return "class ii"... also, formatting may cause issues.... could be adapted as a hybrid with an if statement

Answer (score 0):

Try any of this two formulas:

```
="class " & LOOKUP($A1,{0,"i";1,"ii";2.5,"iii";4.5,"iv"})
```

or

```
="class " & LOOKUP($A1,{0,1,2.5,4.5},{"i","ii","iii","iv"})
```

Answer (score -1):

Simplest thing to do is probably just use an if structure like this...

```
=IF(A1<$D$1,$E$1,IF(A1<$D$2,$E$2,IF(A1<$D$3,$E$3,$E$4)))
```

This formula is entered in column B below....

[image]

This sounds very similar to making a histogram. Excel provides a "Frequency" function that can be useful for making histograms. Also, another way to make a histogram in Excel is to use the Analysis Toolpack add-in (needs to be enabled).  It provides a histogram feature as shown below.

[image]

.... Lastly, there's always the option to create a user-defined function with VBA, but that's probably not necessary.